# Show that the idele group of a number field is locally compact

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a number field and $M_k$ the canonical set of places of $k$. Also let $S_\infty$ be the set of Archmedean places of $k$. For each $v\in M_K$ let $k_v$ be the completion of $k$ wrt an absolute value in $v$ and $\mathfrak o_v$ its valuation ring.

Write $\mathbb I$ for its idele group and for any finite set $S$ of places containing $S_\infty$ write $\mathbb I_S=\prod_{v\in S}k_v^\times \times \prod_{v\notin S}\mathfrak o_v^\times$.

I want to show that $\mathbb I$ is locally compact. Does this follow from the fact that each $\mathbb I_S$ is locally compact and any $x\in \mathbb I$ lies in some $\mathbb I_S$?  Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally compact in which topology? You can put many topologies on this set. But of course you mean the topology people usually put on it, the restricted product topology. Well this topology is just made to be locally compact. See for instance, the beginning of Section 13.3 in Deitmar-Echterhoff: Principles of Harmonic Analysis, 2nd Ed.

Comment: I was just wondering what other topologies you can put on this set. regards

Comment: Well, there's the product topology and there is the restricted topology of the adeles, for instance.